# Conditional property mapping in Automapper not working

Tags: c#, automapper

I am using Automapper 6.2.0 and I have the following classes:

```
public class User
{
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public string Street { get; set; }
}

public class UserDto
{
    public string AddressStreet { get; set; }
}
```

My mapping is configured as follows:

```
        CreateMap<UserDto, User>()
            .ForPath(dest => dest.Address.Street, opt => opt.Condition(cond => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(cond.Source.AddressStreet)))
            .ForPath(dest => dest.Address.Street, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.AddressStreet));
```

I map UserDto to User like so:

```
var userDto = new UserDto{ AddressStreet = null };
var user = mapper.Map<User>(userDto);
var address = user.Address;//I expect the prop to be null, since the mapping condition is not met...
```

This produces a user.Address object instance with Street set to null. I would rather have user.Address not be instantiated at all.

Comment: I have the same problem. One would think when the condition is false, the behavior would be the same as when there is no mapping defined for `Address.Street` at all. Seems to be a bug in Automapper.

Comment: @thatWiseGuy According to the creators, this is by design... https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/2429

Answer (score 1):

Your mapping configuration throws following exception.

```
System.ArgumentException occurred
HResult=0x80070057
Message=Expression 'dest => dest.Address.Street' must resolve to top-
level member and not any child object's properties. You can use 
ForPath, a custom resolver on the child type or the AfterMap option 
instead.
Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source>
StackTrace:
at AutoMapper.Internal.ReflectionHelper.FindProperty(LambdaExpression 
lambdaExpression)
at AutoMapper.Configuration.MappingExpression`2.ForMember[TMember]
(Expression`1 destinationMember, Action`1 memberOptions)
at NetCore.AutoMapperProfile..ctor()
```

Try the following Mapping configuration instead:

```
CreateMap<UserDto, User>()
.ForMember(dest => dest.Address, opt => opt.Condition(src => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(src.AddressStreet)))
.ForMember(dest => dest.Address, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.AddressStreet));
```

The above will result in `user.Address = null`

Comment: My bad, I had copied the wrong code version. It is revised now.

Comment: You are correct that the above code results in user.Address being null, but it won't work whenever userDto.AddressStreet is not null - the exception is Error mapping types, since Address is an object, and AddressStreet is a string.